# Cannot run NodeJS on electron App with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

[image: Error I get]

This error occurs when I run the package.
This is my electron.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
electron.remote.require('../server/server.js')
const path = require('path');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 900, height: 680, webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }});

  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/');
  if (isDev) {
    // Open the DevTools.
    //BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension('<location to your react chrome extension>');
    //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => mainWindow = null);
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const path = require("path");
const Shell = require('node-powershell');


const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')))
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000',credentials:true,allowedHeaders:['Origin']}));


const ps = new Shell({
    verbose: true,
    executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
    noProfile: true,
  });


const AdobeController = require('./Controllers/AdobeController')(app,ps)
const PrinterController = require('./Controllers/PrinterController')(app,ps)

AdobeController.index();
PrinterController.index();






app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

When I package it and run it, the exe file installation gives me that error once I install the app on my desktop.

It runs fine in the dev environment without any packaging, just running the dev script in my package.json. 
Cannot manage to integrate the node server.

Comment: Try using `path.join(__dirname, "../server/server.js")` instead

Comment: No chance that works mate